# Deductive proof question - similar properties?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, quadratics

I am doing a deductive proof question, and am a bit stuck.

I've managed to do the first part, which was to prove that:

$\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\ge xy$

I did this by starting with

$(x-y)^2\ge 0$

and rearranging

The second part wants me to use the first part, and prove that:

$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge xy + yz + zx$

I'm stuck, specifically because it says "using the first part, and 2 similar properties".
What might these properties be? Is it referring to the property that squares are always greater than 0?
Any hints would be really helpful please.

Comment: "Similar properties" (in this case) just means using $x$ and $z$ instead of $x$ and $y$, and then using $y$ and $z$ instead of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Understood, nina?

Comment: I understand thank you!